# Randomly push names into one of two arrays

Tags: javascript

I have an object with two arrays (_licky, _unlucky). and methods that randomly push names into one of the two arrays. But my code does not work for some reason... What is wrong with my code?

```js
const luckGame = {
    _lucky: [],
    _unlucky: [],
    pushGamer(name) {
        return name;
    },
    getRandomNumber (random) {
        return random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    },
    pushGamerIntoArray () {
        return {
            if (this.getRandomNumber() === 0 ) {
                this._lucky.push(this.pushGamer());
            } else {
                this._unlucky.push(this.pushGamer());
            }
        };
    },
};

this.pushGamer('John');
this.pushGamer('Nick');
this.pushGamer('Maria');
this.pushGamer('Sarah');
this.pushGamer('Ron');
this.pushGamer('Lisa');


console.log(luckGame._lucky);
console.log(luckGame._unlucky);
```

Comment: `return { if (` is invalid syntax, and `this.pushGamer` makes no sense at the top level, `this` at that point is either the global object or `undefined`

Comment: You're also never calling `pushGamerIntoArray`.

Comment: yes, I noticed that just a min ago..thanks

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Now it works. thank you all!!

```
const luckGame = {
    _lucky: [],
    _unlucky: [],

    getRandomNumber (random) {
        return random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    },
    pushGamerIntoArray (name) {
        if (this.getRandomNumber() === 0 ) {
            return this._lucky.push(name);
        } else {
            return this._unlucky.push(name);
        }
    },
};



luckGame.pushGamerIntoArray('John');
console.log(luckGame._lucky);
console.log(luckGame._unlucky);
```

Answer (score 0):

There were a few small errors on your part. I have rewritten it in a class variant. It works, but I would still improve a few things. You can test it a bit.

```js
const luckyGame = class {  
  
  constructor() {    
    this._lucky = [],
    this._unlucky = []
  }
  
  pushGamer(name) {
    this.pushGamerIntoArray(name)
  }
  
  getRandomNumber (random) 
  {
    return random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
  }
  
  pushGamerIntoArray (newGamerName) 
  {   
     if (this.getRandomNumber() === 0 ) {
        this._lucky.push(newGamerName)
     } else {
       this._unlucky.push(newGamerName)
     }   
  }
  
  getLuckies () {
   return this._lucky
  }
  
  getUnluckies () {
   return this._unlucky
  }  
}

let luckygame = new luckyGame()
luckygame.pushGamer('John');
luckygame.pushGamer('Nick');
luckygame.pushGamer('Maria');
luckygame.pushGamer('Sarah');
luckygame.pushGamer('Ron');
luckygame.pushGamer('Lisa');
luckygame.pushGamer('John');

console.log(luckygame.getLuckies());
console.log(luckygame.getUnluckies());
```